# Get angle of rotation after rotating a view

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, rotation, cgaffinetransform

Let's say I rotate a view using the following method:

```
            CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity();
            t.Rotate (angle);
            CGAffineTransform transforms = t;
            view.Transform = transforms;
```

How can I get the current rotation angle of this view without keeping track of what i put in the angle variable when I initially did the CGAffineTransform?  Is it related to the view.transform.xx/view.transform.xy values?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what these `xx` and `xy` and all other similar members mean exactly, but my **guess*** is that You won't be able to trace back the applied transformations using solely those values (it would be like tracing back `1+2+3+4` only knowing that You started off with `1` and ended up with `10` - **I think***).

In that case my suggestion would be to derive from the `CGAffineTransform` and store the desired values, but since it's a structure You cannot do that, so in my opinion Your best choice is to write a wrapper class, like so:

```
class MyTransform
{
    //wrapped transform structure
    private CGAffineTransform transform;

    //stored info about rotation
    public float Rotation { get; private set; }

    public MyTransform()
    {
        transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity();
        Rotation = 0;
    }

    public void Rotate(float angle)
    {
        //rotate the actual transform
        transform.Rotate(angle);
        //store the info about rotation
        Rotation += angle;
    }

    //lets You expose the wrapped transform more conveniently
    public static implicit operator CGAffineTransform(MyTransform mt)
    {
        return mt.transform;
    }
}
```

Now the defined operator lets You use this class like this:

```
//do Your stuff
MyTransform t = new MyTransform();
t.Rotate(angle);
view.Transform = t;
//get the rotation
float r = t.Rotation;

//unfortunately You won't be able to do this:
float r2 = view.Transform.Rotation;
```

As You can see this approach has it's limitations, but You can always use only one instance of `MyTransform` to apply all sorts of transformations and store that instance somewhere (or, possibly, a collection of such transforms).

You may also want to store/expose other transformations like *scale* or *translate* in the `MyTransform` class, but I believe You'll know where to go from here.

**feel free to correct me if I'm wrong*

Comment: Your approach is solid and exactly what I'll go with for now.  But if anyone has any light to shine on the subject feel free!